# OSX bash recursively find files sorted by size except in folder

Tags: macos, bash, file, search, file-listing

I came across the following command, which *nearly* does what I need:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l | sort -k5,5rn > ~/files.txt`

Now, I don't have a clue what any of this means (would love an explanation, but not that important).

The one thing I need to add is to not bother with specific folders (i.e. I have a Documents folder with 10s of thousands of Word docs, which is making this command take a long long time).

Can anyone suggest an addition to the above command that will have find ignore a given folder(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exclude paths matching `*/Documents/*` from `find`:

```
find . -type f ! -path "*/Documents/*" -print 0 | ...
```

Comment: Great thanks!  Lauri's answer for thoroughness, but your answer is precisely the answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked for an explanation...

```
find . -type f -print0
```

That's the `find` utility, which travels through the file system to find something that matches what you want it to.  The `.` essentially means it will try to find anything, but since you specified `-type f` it will only find "regular files."  `-print0`, as you may have guessed, simply prints the full path to the standard output (useful for piping).  It uses a null character at the end of each line (as opposed to `-print`, this will be relevant in a moment).

```
xargs -0 ls -l
```

`xargs` takes a list of things from standard input and then executes a given command ("utility") using what is passed to it as an argument.  In this case, the utility is the command `ls -l` so xargs takes the results from `find` and performs `ls -l` on them, giving you the long, full path; this is basically just a way to turn your list of files into a list of files with information such as size.  The `-0` option allows xargs to interpret null characters as the separator between lines, which exists (almost?) solely to allow it to work with the `-print0` option above.

```
sort -k5,5rn > ~/files.txt
```

`sort` is pretty cool.  It sorts things.  `-k` tells it which column to sort by, in this case column 5 (and only column 5).  The `rn` bit means sort using numbers and reverse the order.  The default is largest at the bottom so this puts largest first.  Sorting numerically can get confusing if you use unit-suffixes (B, K, M, G, etc.) using `ls -lh`.

Answer (score 1):

Different options or other ways to find large files:

- `find ~ -size +100M ! -path ~/Documents\* ! -path ~/Library\*`
- `find ~ -size +100M | grep -v "^$HOME/Documents/" | while IFS= read -r l; do stat -f'%z %N' "$l"; done | sort -rn`
- `shopt -s extglob; find ~/!(Documents) -type f -exec stat -f'%z %N' {} \; | sort -rn | head -n200`
- `mdfind 'kMDItemFSSize>=1e8&&kMDItemContentTypeTree!=public.directory' | while IFS= read -r l; do stat -f'%z %N' "$l"; done | sort -rn`

You might also just use Finder:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it's a USB hard drive, with a VHD disk image on it, which is mounted via Parallels. Finder doesn't show any results.  Maybe it would if I waited long enough, but there is no indication of progress.